# Extract HTML Table from nth Row using Data Scraping in UiPath

Tags: uipath

I have a table in a web page with let's say 10 rows with two columns: Col1 and Col2.

How can I extract data from nth Row row to mth Row, for example I want to extract data from 3rd row to next 5 rows i.e. till 7th row using data **scraping** in UiPath.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the whole table then use a Filter Datatable activity to extract the rows you want.

Comment: I can not extract the whole table as it has 90000+ rows in it and while scraping UiPath generates error "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" and returns blank data table.